# Incorporate String into a Range (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a code to have a user enter in a year, to which excel would then find in a row, and then autofill the formula in that column. I have managed to be able to get the input and column aspect down, but am struggling with how to incorporate my sting into a range. Please help!

Code below.

```
Sub Copy_formula()
    NewPageName = InputBox("Enter in Year")

    Dim rFind As Range

    Sheets("data_calc").Select

    With Range("A2:AH2")
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=NewPageName, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox rFind.Column
        End If

    End With

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, "rFind"), Cells(2393, "rFind"))
    Range(Cells(3, "rFind"), Cells(2393, "rFind")).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to use the value stored in the `rFind` cell as the column number, or the `rFind` cell itself for its own column.

Answer (score 0):

`"rFind"` within double quotes is a `String` which VBA will try to convert to a column number within a `Cells()` statement.  As columns run from "A" to "XFD", anything beyond that should cause an error.  So loose the double quotes.

However, that won't entirely solve your problem.  The default return for a `Range` object is its `.Value` property.

What you want is the `Range.Column` property.

So change your `Range(Cells(3, "rFind"), Cells(2393, "rFind"))` to:

```
Range(Cells(3, rFind.Column), Cells(2393, rFind.Column))
```

Comment: Awesome! I still had issues with the auto fill destination, so I used your suggestion with FillDown and it worked! Thanks for the fast response!